# Can anyone help me recreate this effect? (3D)

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Whenever I try to make the second text in 3D to look like the first one, it seems that I can't change the angle of the 3D effect. What I mean is that the original 3D effect seems to go down and mine is going inwards. I want to change it without affecting the original text (warping it in perspective)

[image]

PS: I would also appreciate if someone can come up with an idea of how to make the shiny bevel. I have previously made something similar but this has a stroke and the chrome effect is in it, and I have made only the chrome effect previously.

Answer (score 2):

This is modified manually starting from the yellowish part of your TOP. It was separated with the magic wand, pasted onto an empty layer and colored to solid yellow taken from your model image. Not trying anything flashy such as 3D or vector shapes. A coarsely resembling copy appeared when enough stuff was piled:

[image]

Your image fortunately had high resolution.Trying the same at normal screen resolution leads to a hopeless mess. The best results can be got by starting in vector domain.

The uppermost surface of the text TOP has a shrinked copy. It has own bevel with white light edge and dark red shadow edge. I didnt bother to search proper settings for proper Bevel & Emboss, only made a white copy and a dark orange copy and shifted them a little apart to simulate embossing. The shrinked copies of TOP were made by shrinking the selection (+Copy&Paste) after the full size copy was made in the beginning.  If you look carefully, you see many corners have a chamfer. This is from shrinking the selection. An exact shrink is possible in vector domain as offset curve.

The topmost shrinked TOP got a gradient fill from yellow to light brown.

The full size yellow TOP got layer style Beve&Emboss, the settings are onscreen. The replica is not complete, only a little resembling. The shading colors are not black and white, but dark reds both and their blending mode = multiply. This phase takes time, if one wants exact copy. I do not know would it even be possible. The shading can be partially painted manually or from totally different program than my antique Photoshop from far before CC.

The dark 3D-ish bodies of the characters are made manually:

- make a dark red copy of text TOP as the bottom layer
- Shift the layer downwards and then T and P separately sideways (Processing of P was stopped here)
- spray a little lighter red onto O to get the shading
- Take the polygonal Lasso and make the needed selections to complete the body of T and spraying the lighter red shading.

Spray = A soft brush with low opacity or in airbrush mode with slow flow. Have a selection ON when spraying, otherwise you create a mess. If this is something never tried, preferably spray onto a new layer to prevent messing something already good. Merge the sprayed layers when you are fully satisfied.

Comment: You're awesome! Is there a chance that you kept the psd file?

Comment: @lucellent it's here https://www.dropbox.com/s/kyg7772ftrvfhtv/TOP.psd?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

After using 3d to convert the text, select the Rotate 3d object toll.

Hold  <kbd>shift</kbd>  to constrains the angle and drag Up.

About the gold style, it is probably a Style.
I think it is better you make another question about styles.

See the image blow:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think the 3d method worked but I had to drag it way up so do you have an idea how do I put it back in the original position without affecting the 3D effect?